# How I can align MenuItems in Menu to right?

Tags: wpf, xaml

In a menu bar, I want to get the two last buttons (here `RUN` and `ADD`) to the right instead of left

I tried to use `HorizontalAlignment` without success:

```xml
<Menu>
    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>
    <MenuItem Header="FILE"/>
    <MenuItem Header="EDIT"/>
    <MenuItem Header="VIEW"/>
    <MenuItem Header="RUN" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    <MenuItem Header="ADD" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in the

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

This is what describes the container your MenuItems will belong in. You need to use a panel here which allows you to horizontally align items to the right within it.

You could try keeping it as a DockPanel:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
```

And adding

```
DockPanel.Dock="Right"
```

To the MenuItems you need to align right, and

```
DockPanel.Dock="Left"
```

To the others. If this does not work, there are plenty of other panels you can use in place of the `DockPanel` in the `ItemsPanelTemplate`.